# Why does Safari calculate REMs in media queries differently than other browsers?

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design

While designing a responsive layout I'm running into an issue where my `@media` breakpoints are rendering inconsistently across browsers.

My layout is built from [Automattic/_s](https://github.com/Automattic/_s)

*See my CSS at* (https://gist.github.com/mikeritter/1e7195e91239faead4ff).

Note the font size reset on line 70:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%; /* Corrects text resizing oddly in IE6/7 when body font-size is set using em units http://clagnut.com/blog/348/#c790 */
    overflow-y: scroll; /* Keeps page centered in all browsers regardless of content height */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* Prevents iOS text size adjust after orientation change, without disabling user zoom */
    -ms-text-size-adjust:     100%; /* www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/controlling_text_size_in_safari_for_ios_without_disabling_user_zoom/ */
}
```

then my media query breakpoints based on 10/16 = 62.5% to set REMs at 10px

Safari renders my breakpoints per the calculation ( 96rem = 960px), but other browsers break at higher resolutions.

Comment: I'm noting this link http://filamentgroup.com/lab/how-we-learned-to-leave-body-font-size-alone.html

Comment: Setting `html` `font-size` to `10px` has no effect

Comment: Have the same issue. Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody else ends up here from google:
I ended up asking a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57517896/media-query-rem-calculation-browser-inconsistency), which ultimately led me to a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47409585/using-rem-units-in-media-queries-and-as-width), which I think also answers this question. Basically, Safari is intentionally ignoring the [media query spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries/#units):

> Relative units in media queries are based on the initial value, which means that units are never based on results of declarations. For example, in HTML, the em unit is relative to the initial value of font-size, defined by the user agent or the user’s preferences, not any styling on the page.

So, all other browsers will use the default font size provided by the browser (almost universally 16px today, as zoom is now the standard for a11y users instead of a modified default font size). The result is that **for all intents and purposes, in media queries 1rem = 16px, always**.